# google maps api infobox plugin and multiple markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

How can I create multiple markers with different content when using infobox plugin http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/infobox-basic.html

I was creating var marker1, var marker2 etc but I think this is not really nice method and I have the same content in all infowindows...

Answer (score 16):

You just need to generate the markers with a factory of some sort, e.g:

```
function initMarkers(map, markerData) {
    var newMarkers = []

    // Here's where all the really verbose code goes. Loop through `markerData` to
    // create each marker.  See the full code in the js fiddle

    return newMarkers;
}

function initialize_google_map() {
    //Here the call to initMarkers() is made with the necessary data for each marker.
    //All markers are then returned as an array into the markers variable, Usually you'd 
    //get the data from server or something, here it's just shown inline.

    var markers = initMarkers(map, [
        { latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307), address: "Address 1", state: "State 1" },
        { latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47420, -123.75703), address: "Address 2", state: "State 2" },
        { latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47530, -123.78040), address: "Address 3", state: "State 3" }
    ]);
}
```

Check out the full example with HTML and whatnot [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccJ9p/7/).

Answer (score 3):

**For infobox toggle onclick replace :**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        newMarkers[i].infobox.open(theMap, this);
        theMap.panTo(markerData[i].latLng);
    }
})(marker, i));
```

**By :**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        for ( h = 0; h < newMarkers.length; h++ ) {
            newMarkers[h].infobox.close();
        }
        newMarkers[i].infobox.open(theMap, this);
        theMap.panTo(markerData[i].latLng);
    }
})(marker, i));
```

Answer (score 0):

@DonamiteIsTnt your example is really helpful but markerData[i] doesn't have any property latLng i think use markerData[i].position. It worked for me.